# Can't display variable wpf xaml c#

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to display a variable that might change overtime, i tried this :

```xml
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding Req_Hexa}">
       <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="270,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" Text= "{Binding Path = myText, ElementName=windowElement, Mode=TwoWay}" />
       <TextBox x:Name="Val_Buffer_ReqHexa" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="52,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Buffer}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="500" KeyDown="Properties_KeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

```c#
 public string myText {get; set;}
 public void test()
 {
      myText = " testttttttttttttttttttt";
 }
```

[The variable result is supposed to be displayed here but instead there is a blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBllp.png)

I tried every way of displaying a variable I could find

Comment: I do not see INotifyPropertyChanged implementation in your property...

Comment: could you elaborate ? I'm totally new in wpf

Answer (score 0):

Try to set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged:

```
   <TextBlock Text= "{Binding myText, ElementName=windowElement, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Buffer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
 public string myText 
 {
     get; 
     set
     {
        RaisePropertyChanged(myText);
     }
 }
 public void test()
 {
      myText = " testttttttttttttttttttt";
 }

public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Edit:

We got the problem. In WPF you need to have a Page (Diag_Prog.xaml) and a code behind file (Diag_Prog.xaml.cs) which are connected automatically. Just add a page to your project:

[image: page]

In Visual Studio it should look like this:

[image: files]

Comment: I just did what u said, but still the same result.....

Comment: Is the c# code in the code behind file (<YourXmlPage>.xaml.cs) or in a different file?

Comment: I got Diag_Prog.xaml and Diag_Prog.cs

Comment: Has this solved your problem?